# Why does arp take so long to execute?

Tags: networking, command-line

I'am on a wireless network. On windows, `arp -a` doesn't take long to complete, but on  Ubuntu it takes a very long time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess windows `arp -a` doesn't do name lookup. Just use `arp -n` on linux and it will be instant.

Comment: Use `arp -an` on MacOS for the same (fast) results. Just the `-n` option seems illegal here